# Is there a better/more elegant way of performing a time-out loop in BASH script?

Tags: bash

In my bash (4.4) script, I want to delay processing whilst some other task is running (I know about 'wait' but it doesn't work in my scenario as I'm calling a third-party process that seems to spawn multiple processes and 'wait' in my script appears to return once the parent process has completed, not the parent and all its children).

I'm also trying, where possible to use 'printf' for date/time calculations instead of 'date', largely to favour built-ins over external commands.

So far I have this:

```
_max_wait_seconds=120
printf -v _end_time '%(%s)T' -1
(( _end_time += _max_wait_seconds ))
while <process is active> && [[ $(printf '%(%s)T' -1) -lt "${_end_time}" ]]; do
  sleep ??s
done
```

It seems to work fine, but was just wondering if there's a better way of achieving the same outcome?

Comment: `<process is active>` so what is there in real code?

Comment: Where do you start the process that you want to test for `<process is active>`? You say "seems to spawn multiple processes" - what makes you **think** ("seems") it might do that? Do you know for sure if it does or not?

Comment: Not sure how knowing what is happening in <process is active> is relevant? I left it out because it's just a 'black box' in this instance. It will run until completion/timeout.

Comment: And yes, I said 'seems' but I have seen the parent spawn children and also that the children are still active when the 'wait' command returns control - I've proved this through testing. Sorry if my phrasing was not precise enough

Comment: You can simply wait on `sleep $_wait_max_seconds &`, then resume your script, or do you want to regain control if the process finishes early?

Comment: Question seems opinion-based if it's just asking about the best way to busy-wait. `printf` vs `$SECONDS` vs counting loop increments are all fine.

Comment: `how knowing what is happening in <process is active> is relevant?` It is relevant because there might be ways to optimize it. If checking for existence of a file, there is `inotifywait`. If checking for existence of a pid, there is `tail --pid`. etc. There may be event-based ways to check for poll-based events.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the timeout processing by using the Bash built-in [SECONDS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SECONDS) variable:

```
_max_wait_seconds=120
_end_time=$(( SECONDS + _max_wait_seconds ))
while <process is active> && (( SECONDS < _end_time )); do
    sleep ??s
done
```

- `SECONDS` expands to the number of seconds since the shell was started.
- This should work on old versions of Bash, including the default Bash (version 3.2) on macOS.  The `%(fmt)T` specifier for `printf` was introduced in Bash 4.2.